# Available RAM recommendation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have an production environment running SharePoint 2013.  Total RAM on each server is 16GB and RAM utilization hits (and goes over 90%) on the web front ends quite often.  Our SharePoint engineer responsible for the farm says that 90% RAM utilization is fine for a server running SharePoint.  This doesn't seem right.  Anyone have any feedback regarding running servers with RAM utilization so high?  Does anyone run their farms with such a high threshold?  Or would recommend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule for SharePoint; and the mantra of 'unused RAM is wasted RAM', however I personally wouldn't run with >70% utilization in order to absorb any spikes in usage.

Comment: I would totally agree with this and in addition it is important to know that some of the SharePoint services (BDC) stop working when RAM is utilized more than 95%, so 90% utilization is pretty much walking on the edge...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I was beginning to question my sanity as no one else on the team was questioning this.  Granted the team are developers, not system engineers or admins.  When prod is at 80% I usually begin the process to get RAM.  At 90% I'm escalating things to get more RAM before we have issues...not trying to assure people everything is 'fine'.

Comment: Another indication is if you see warnings in the Application Event Log about Distributed Cache low memory scenarios.